# Magento 2: How to set VaultProvider?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, model, payment-gateway, paypal-payments-pro

I'm working on custom payment system in which I am using Magento2 default vault functionality. Everything is working fine when if I replace below code in file `Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault` into `authorize()` or `capture()` methods.

```
$commandExecutor = $this->commandManagerPool->get(
        $this->getVaultProvider()->getCode()
    );
```

to

```
$commandExecutor = $this->commandManagerPool->get(
        "method_code"
    );
```

My question is how can I assign `vaultprovider`? so I can get method code directly form `vaultprovider` object.

Note: I'm not placing an order in Magento, I just authorize or capture amount from third party payment gateway system(**paypal pro**) in my custom module.

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/643

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some R&D I got the solution myself.

First I created a class in my module:

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Payment;
class Payflowpro 
{
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Vault\Model\VaultPaymentInterface $vault
) {
   $this->vault = $vault

}
  public function mymethod($payment,$amount)
  {
    $this->vault->authorize($payment,$amount);
  }
}
```

Here I passed an object of `Vault` Class.

In second step 1 created `di.xml` in my module and write below code:

```
<type name="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Payment\Payflowpro">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="vault" xsi:type="object">PayflowProCreditCardVaultFacade</argument>
    </arguments>
 </type>
```

here type is used for assigning object value which I passed in my module class

Now last steps I creates `VirtualType` in my `di.xml` for assigning `provider` to Vault Class.

```
 <virtualType name="PayflowProCreditCardVaultFacade" type="Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="config" xsi:type="object">PayflowProVaultPaymentConfig</argument>
        <argument name="valueHandlerPool" xsi:type="object">PayflowProVaultPaymentValueHandlerPool</argument>
        <argument name="vaultProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent</argument>
        <argument name="code" xsi:type="const">Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent::CC_VAULT_CODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Comment: Nice solutions.

Comment: Good catch @Yogesh :) +1 from me

Comment: @yogesh, Can you provide info, how can I use vault for my custom payment method?

Comment: @Keyur I am trying to add Vault to the payfort module by following the official doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-intro.html, but i cannot get the dependency injection correct. I tried to copy the di.xml from the braintree module but it is also very confusing. the code inside the VaultDetailsHandler which is used as handler is not getting executed. What is your opinion about using 
**sales_order_payment_save_after** or  **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** event observers to add token to vault. Is there any good example available ?

Comment: @Yogesh : Does the Magento_Vault functionalty work with custom payment method? or there is limitation like braintree & paypal.

Comment: @Yogesh : could you please answer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302818/implementing-magento-vault-with-custom-payment-method-magento-2