# How to use the vault in custom payment module.

Tags: module, payment-methods, magento2.2.2, vault

I am working on custom payment module with Authorize technique using XML API based.

I need to use Magento out of box vault module to save customer card details.
Any one have knowledge on this How Can I use this vault to save card.?

Thanks.

Comment: See link:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176777/24878

Comment: Follow devdoc document: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-intro.html

Comment: @PrincePatel, to use of vault in my payment module, what is this mean "the payment method must be implemented using Magento payment gateway"

Comment: @Charlie : Have you able to use vault feature for your custom module? if yes then could you please guide me. actually I have also the exact same requirement.

Comment: @BalwantSingh, my code is here https://github.com/Worldpay/Worldpay-Magento2-CG.

Answer (score 1):

**Add vault to module dependencies**

You need to add dependencies on the `Magento_Vault` module in the payment method’s `module.xml` files.

**Example:** adding Vault module dependencies for the Braintree payment method

> app/code/Magento/Braintree/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Braintree" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            ...
            <module name="Magento_Vault"/>
            ...
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Now configuration vault payment**

You need to configure the main parameters of the vault implementation in the `config.xml` file of your payment method module:

**model** - instance of the vault payment implementation, configured in di.xml.

**title** - vault payment method title; can be overwritten in the store configuration.

These parameters are specified in the section defined by the unique vault implementation code. They are the minimum required to create vault payment. All other payment settings are inherited from the payment provider integration.

**Additional configuration might be required depending on your implementation.**

The following example is the `config.xml` file of the Braintree payment method:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <braintree>
                <model>BraintreeFacade</model>
                ...
            </braintree>
            <braintree_cc_vault>
                <model>BraintreeCreditCardVaultFacade</model>
                <title>Stored Cards (Braintree)</title>
            </braintree_cc_vault>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

**More at:**

1) http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-di.html

2) [Magento 2: How to set VaultProvider?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176325/magento-2-how-to-set-vaultprovider/176777#176777)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to add Vault to the payfort module by following the official doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-intro.html, but i cannot get the dependency injection correct. I tried to copy the di.xml from the braintree module but it is also very confusing.  the code inside the VaultDetailsHandler which is used as handler is not getting executed. What is your opinion about using 
**sales_order_payment_save_after** or  **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** event observers to add token to vault

Comment: have you get any solution @SreejithSasidharan

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.2
I made a payment gateway with a safe, it saves and lists the cards, but it doesn't go through the custom builders at the end of the purchase, finishing normally.
Without the card saved (vault) it ends the order and passes the builders normally

```
<virtualType name="CustomCcVaultPaymentConfig" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="methodCode" xsi:type="const">Vendor\CustomPayment\Gateway\Config::CC_VAULT_CODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="CustomCcVaultPaymentValueHandler" type="VaultPaymentDefaultValueHandler">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configInterface" xsi:type="object">CustomCcVaultPaymentConfig</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="CustomCcVaultPaymentValueHandlerPool" type="VaultPaymentValueHandlerPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">CustomCcVaultPaymentValueHandler</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="CustomCcVaultFacade" type="Magento\Vault\Model\Method\Vault">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="config" xsi:type="object">CustomCcVaultPaymentConfig</argument>
        <argument name="valueHandlerPool" xsi:type="object">CustomCcVaultPaymentValueHandlerPool</argument>
        <argument name="vaultProvider" xsi:type="object">CustomCcFacade</argument>
        <argument name="code" xsi:type="const">Vendor\CustomPayment\Gateway\Config::CC_VAULT_CODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I followed the documentation and the vendor.
Detail that in the debug comes canCancel false

Payload on the front goes with the right hash.

What would it need to pass in the builds used in the module?